# How to solve multiple dependent differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, matlab, symbolic-computation, integral-dependence

I have next differential equation:

$$ (x_0x_3)'=-(x_1x_2)'+8\cdot(-x_2'-\dfrac{x_1'}{x_0}+\dfrac{x_1x_0'}{x_0^2})$$

where $x_0'=\dfrac{dx_0}{dz}$, and it means the same for every sign $'$.

On the other side $x_0=(1+64(1-z))^{0.5}=f(z)$.

I need to solve the first equation on that way that I need to find $x_3$. But because I have dependence $x_0=f(z)$, and because also $x_1=f(x_0)$ and $x_2=f(x_0)$, that means that they are all also dependent on $z$: $x_1=f(z)$ and $x_2=f(z)$, and it is impossible to integrate upper equation on this way:

$$\dfrac{d}{dz}(x_0x_3)=...  \,\,\,  / \cdot dz$$
$$d(x_0x_3)=... \,\,\, /integration$$
because I will lost some dependence between variables.

I am trying to do all this in Mupad which is part of Matlab and it is according to my opinion appropriate for symbolical equations. So I have tried to tell Mupad that I have $$x_0=(1+64(1-z))^{0.5}$$ $$x_1=8(\dfrac{1}{x_0}-1)$$ $$x_2=-\dfrac{x_1^2}{2x_0}+\dfrac{8}{x_0}(-x_1-ln(x_0))$$ and it accepted it. But as next step where I need to solve upper differential equation i tried with this:

```
ode::solve({-(x0*x3)'-(x1*x2)'+8*(-x2'-x1'/x0+x1*x0'/x0^2)=0},x3)
```

And also with different combinations with initial conditions

```
 ode::solve({-(x0*x3)'-(x1*x2)'+8*(-x2'-x1'/x0+x1*x0'/x0^2)=0,x3(0)=0},x3)
```

I always got:

```
Error: Invalid arguments
```

Am I on the right way to solve this equation on this way and with Mupad and what would be incorrect here? Or would be correct way to solve this?

Comment: Use the product rule on the LHS of the original DE. Plug in what $x_0, x_1,$ and $x_2$ are (known functions of $z$). Then you will have a first-order linear equation in $x_3$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $x_0=f(z)$ and $x_1=x_2=f(x_0)=f(f(z)),$ where 
$$f(z)=\sqrt{1+64(1-z)}.$$
Define $x_4=x_0\cdot x_3$. The original DE becomes
\begin{align*}
x_4'&=-(x_1x_2)'+8\cdot\left(-x_2'-\dfrac{x_1'}{x_0}+\dfrac{x_1x_0'}{x_0^2}\right) \\
x_4'&=-((x_1)^2)'+8\cdot\left(-x_1'-\dfrac{x_1'}{x_0}+\dfrac{x_1x_0'}{x_0^2}\right) \\
x_4'&=-((f(f(z)))^2)'+8\cdot\left(-(f(f(z)))'-\dfrac{(f(f(z)))'}{f(z)}+\dfrac{f(f(z))\,f'(z)}{f^2(z)}\right)\\
x_4'&=-2f(f(z))\cdot f'(f(z))\cdot f'(z)+8\cdot\left(\dfrac{-f^2(z)(f(f(z)))'-f(z)(f(f(z)))'+f(f(z))\,f'(z)}{f^2(z)}\right).
\end{align*}
We simplify what's in the parentheses:
\begin{align*}
()&=\dfrac{-f^2(z)(f(f(z)))'-f(z)(f(f(z)))'+f(f(z))\,f'(z)}{f^2(z)}\\
&=\dfrac{-f^2(z)f'(f(z))f'(z)-f(z)f'(f(z))f'(z)+f(f(z))\,f'(z)}{f^2(z)} \\
&=f'(z)\cdot\dfrac{-f^2(z)f'(f(z))-f(z)f'(f(z))+f(f(z))}{f^2(z)}.
\end{align*}
Plugging this back in:
$$x_4'=f'(z)\cdot\left(8\cdot\dfrac{-f^2(z)f'(f(z))-f(z)f'(f(z))+f(f(z))}{f^2(z)}-2f(f(z))\cdot f'(f(z))\right). $$
I would use Mathematica to define `f[x_]`, and then simply integrate this expression with respect to $z$. That will give you $x_4$. Then you can solve for $x_3$.

Comment: As result in Mupad when I write that `p34(z) = -diff(p1,z)*p2-diff(p2,z)*p1-8*diff(p2,z)-8*diff(p1,z)/p0+8*p1*diff(p0,z)/p0^2` and as next step I use `int(p34(z),z)` I got only the same row as mine is, do you know how to get exact solution? (I used $p$ instead of $x$).

Comment: I can't answer MuPAD questions. There is no computer algebra system superior to Mathematica when it comes to symbolic manipulation. You can access the Wolfram Dev Platform for free (sign up for an account), and get at least access to the language. You won't get unlimited compute time, but it can do an awful lot. I never recommend MATLAB for symbolic computations.

Answer (score 1):

Making substitutions and developing the DE gives

$$
x_3(z) x_0'(z)+\frac{8 x_1'(z)}{x_0(z)}+x_0(z)
   x_3'(z)+x_2(z) x_1'(z)+(x_1(z)+8) x_2'(z)-\frac{8x_1(z) x_0'(z)}{x_0(z)^2}=0
$$

Solving for $x_3(z)$ gives

$$
x_3'(z)= \frac{x_1(z) \left(8 x_0'(z)-x_0(z)^2 x_2'(z)\right)-x_0(z) \left(x_0(z)
   \left(x_3(z) x_0'(z)+x_2(z) x_1'(z)+8 x_2'(z)\right)+8 x_1'(z)\right)}{x_0(z)^3}
$$

and solving the $x_3(z)$ DE

$$
x_3(z) = \frac{x_0(z) \left(C_3-(x_1(z)+8) x_2(z)\right)-8 x_1(z)}{x_0(z)^2}
$$

All this was made with the help from a symbolic processor. I hope this helps.

Follows the MATHEMATICA script to obtain those results.

`d[x1_, x2_, x3_, z_]:= D[x0[z] x3, z]+D[x1 x2, z]+8(D[x2, z]+D[x1, z]/x0[z]-x1 D[x0[z],z]/x0[z]^2)
dx30 = d[x1[z], x2[z], x3[z], z]
solx3 = Solve[dx30 == 0, x3'[z]][[1]]
equx3 = solx3 /. Rule -> Equal
solx3 = DSolve[equx3, x3, z][[1]]
x3z = x3[z] /. solx3`

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure that this is correct solution, because of that multiple dependencies. Because of that I wrote my equation on the way that I have only $z$ and $p_3(z)$, $p_3'(z)$, and tried to solve it with ode in Mupad, but as solution I got exactly the same row as I wrote, without error, do you know how to write this in better symbolic form: `o := ode(p3'(z) = -diff(p1,z)*p2-diff(p2,z)*p1-8*diff(p2,z)-8*diff(p1,z)/p0+8*p1*diff(p0,z)/p0^2-diff(p0,z)*p3(z),p3(z))`

Comment: , where `p2:=(-ln(1+64*(1-z))+4*(1-1/(1+64*(1-z))^2))/(1+64*(1-z))` and `p1:=8*(1/(1+64*(1-z))-1) ` `p0=sqrt(1+64*(1-z))`

Comment: and with `solve(o)` I got some integral under solution, do you know how to get exactly result?

Comment: (I used $p$ instead of $x$).

Comment: @nick_name Regarding symbolic processors I have confidence in MATHEMATICA so I included the small script to reproduce the shown results.